# How to advise maven-jaxb2-plugin to use same class in two places?

Tags: java, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using **maven-jaxb2-plugin** to generate JAXB classes.  I have no control over the WSDL or XSD.

The XSD specifies either a single "MyObject", or a parent object containing a list of "MyObjects".  I know they're the same.  But the plugin doesn't (naturally).  Is there a way I can tell it to use a single (non-inner) class for both?  Otherwise, I would need to write lots of duplicate code...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can control using bindings, for example [here](https://blog.frankel.ch/customize-your-jaxb-bindings/) and you can force to be use same class (you'll get a warning since they are redefined).

Anyway, probably you are using a wrong generated WSDL/XSD with multiple namespaces (e.g. they use the same codebase but are exposing multiple endpoints, for them is the same class but for you are multiple different classes).

Although you *"have no control over the WSDL"* ask for fix it, if not, maybe you can unify (writing one script into your CI/CD pipeline) putting all of them together (e.g. multiple xsd inside one root).

Unfortunately many people write and publish web services incorrectly and produce a lot of (unnecessary) headaches for those of us who use them :/

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked!  And saved a ton of coding!

Comment: This was the final result: <bindings
node="//xs:element[@name='MyParentWithList']//.//xs:element[@name='MyObject']">
   <class ref="my.package..MyObject" />
  </bindings>